# Javascript does't work at first but works on second, third, etc. times

Tags: javascript, jquery

Javascript does't work at first but works on second, third, etc. times.

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

$variation_form = $( '.variations_form');

$variation_form.on( 'show_variation', function( event, variation ){

    if ( variation.variation_description ) {
        $( '.variation-description p').html( variation.variation_description );
    }
})
.on( 'reset_image', function () {

    $('.variation-description p').html('');
});
```

})( jQuery, window, document );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something to fire the events.....

```
$(".myselector").on('click', function() {
    $variation_form.trigger('show_variation');
});
```

[Working Fiddle (again)](http://jsfiddle.net/incept0/3e06hke3/3/)   :P
Full code below...

```
(function($){
    $(function(){  

        $variation_form = $('.variations_form');

        $variation_form.on('show_variation', function (event, variation) {                
            if (variation.variation_description) {
                $('.variation-description p').html(variation.variation_description);
            }
        });

        $variation_form.on('reset_image', function () {
            $('.variation-description p').html('');
        });

        $(".myselector").on('click', function() {
            $variation_form.trigger('show_variation');
        });
     });
 })(jQuery);
```